# Best way to do "exclusive OR open-ended" date query in RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, where-clause

Cunningham's Law: This has to be the best way to accomplish this task. The best.

```
# rubies on railz
# Assume we pass an options hash with, possibly, two dates.
# If both dates: do an inclusive between the two
# If start date: do open-ended search
# Else do close-ended search  

def my_date_helper(options)
  start_date = options[:start_date].try(:beginning_of_day)
  end_date   = (options[:end_date] || 6.months.from_now).end_of_day

  if start_date && end_date
    query.where(created_at: start_date..end_date)
  elsif start_date
    query.where("created_at >= ?", start_date)
  else
    query.where("created_at <= ?", end_date)
  end
end
```

Comment: Is there a problem with this?  In the grand scheme of things it seems readable and accomplishes the task...

Comment: Nick Veys: Thank you for validating. We were unable to come up with a more elegant solution. There are a few ways of writing it, but we found no compelling reason to change. I was hoping that we were missing some new rails helper or stdlib method. Cheers.

Comment: I wonder where `query` is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

Hello my best way per example:

is is camp in sql table is TYPE => DATETIME im using

```
DATE(created_at) BETWEEN ? and ?,start_date,end_date
```

why?

for date time need cast created_at to DATE type if you compare per example 2014-02-10 you need have in sql 2014-02-10 no 2014-02-10 14:00:22

if you need compare TYPE DATE TIME

```
query.where(created_at: start_date..end_date)
```

regards!

Comment: That doesn't accomplish the open-ended, closed-ended issue. We have the exclusive "between" which use has accomplised. However if either of the dates are omitted, we want the method to handle the range appropriately.

Comment: in the best way for sql query date ranges